# How to edit default layout files in Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I've created a ListView in an activity in a java file.  For this LIstView I call the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 layout view which is a default layout that I did not create myself.  I want to create a custom layout in place of simple_list_item_1, but I don't want to have to start from scratch.  How can I find this default layout so I can make slight edits to it?  The reason I don't want to start from scratch is because all I really want to do is make the text size a bit smaller.  If this is possible without editing the file (rather programmatically), then that answer would be fine too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The layout file you're looking for is located in

```
<android-sdk>/platforms/android-7/data/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml
```

Where `<android-sdk>` is where you installed the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that making changes to

```
<android-sdk>/platforms/android-7/data/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml
```

is realy good idea.

I would rather apply changes to Android default layout in java code. Something like this (in your adapter):

```
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) 
{
    if ( null == convertView )
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from( getContext( ) );
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate( android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null );
    }

    TextView textView = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( android.R.id.text1 );

    textView.setText( "Content ..." );
    // Set your font here ...

    return convertView;
}
```